Mirroring - Server network address can not be reached or does not exist (Error: 1418)
I would like to mirror the database I have in my local desktop (192.168.0.80) on my local mini pc (192.168.0.85) that will be on 24 hours a day.
This mini pc will only be used as a consultation for my mobile application, which is why I am choosing to use the "High Performance" option.
But I'm not able to do this mirroring, I can access both databases in any computer without any problem, but can't start mirroring.
Error what I got when I try to mirror:
Error: 1418. The server network address can not be reached or does not exist.
What I tried:

Open port 1433, 5022 in both servers (validated using "telnet ip 5022") and also turning firewall off;
Made a full backup in desktop then restore it in mini pc;
"state_desc" in sys.database_mirroring_endpoints is "STARTED" in both databases.


